# Android ADT plugin error: main.xml: / by zero

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm new to this site so please excuse my formatting issues. My problem is that I get this error in eclipse when I try to add a row to my xml TableLayout in the graphical layout tab of my xml document. My error is the following

```
Exception raised during rendering: / by zero
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

Here is my XML code. For some reason, even though a row is automatically added to the main.xml file, the graphical layout displays an error.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Let me know if you have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong, or if you need more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please remove `android:stretchColumns="*"` From TableLayout.

Or Please provide any number instead of **'*'** like `android:stretchColumns="2"`

Comment: YES! It worked! Thank you so much! Could you please explain why your solution works?

Comment: yeah i will, but i cant do it for 2 more minutes.

Comment: @Vizzle You can stretch all columns by using the value "*" instead of number but in graphical view you can not see your view.

Comment: i think i get it.so the column width will stretch as much as possible without getting larger than the parent's width, but i wont be able to see that in the graphical view.

Comment: i wish i could upvote your answer, but i dont have enough points

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled into the same problem and I guess that we're both following the book "Android for Programmers" by Deitel (in particular, this issue originates in p.127).
I've decided to drop it and look somewhere else.
The book explicitly says to set android:stretchColumns to "*" and a couple of paragraphs later they ask you to add rows to a TableLayout. Have they tested it?

Comment: yeah idk. the it is pretty old though.